# Outlook crashes when trying to dismiss reminder

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, outlook-web-access

Microsoft Outlook 2010 running on Windows 7 crashes and restarts when trying to dismiss/snooze calender reminders. Need help dismissing these 3 reminders

*Outlook only crashes with these 3 reminders.

- Tried Outlook in safe mode and disabling all add-ins.
- Tried restarting computer.
- Tried repairing Microsoft Office.
- Tried \outlook.exe /cleanreminders
- Tried \outlook.exe /firstrun
- Tried \outlook.exe /cleansniff
- Tried \outlook.exe /cleanfreebusy
- Tried Creating a new profile.
- Un-installed/re-installed Microsoft Office 2010
- Tried Scanpst.exe and ***found errors in pst***, tried to repair when found error but program stopped responding. Realized email is not pst but ost???
- Did research and found that KB2553248 is causing this problem? although, I could not find the installed update on the PC so instead tried un-installing Service Pack 1. This did not resolve the problem.

---

****Solved by dismissing reminders from OWA webmail.****

---

This event occured at the same time. Could not find the mentioned add-in "HrEnsureScriptObject".
[image]

Comment: You disabled or deleted the add-ins?

Comment: I disabled the add-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****Solved by dismissing reminders from OWA webmail.****